# Magento 2 load cart page as ajax

Tags: magento2, cart, ajax

How I can load cart page as Ajax?
I create a controller and try to show cart block like below

```
  echo   $block=$this->_view->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart')
        ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
```

but it does not show any thing 
how i can load cart block with all chaild blocks ?

Comment: Do you want to load cart via AJAX?

Comment: @Pribhav cart page with all item